# DriverManager.getConnection("url"); cannot catch any exception

Tags: java, jdbc

Android App is connected to database by using JDBC library.
But DriverManager.getConnection("url") is returning null. So I tried putting "try...catch " like this:

```
      Connection con = null;
      try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("dummy url");
            System.out.println("Connected.");

      }catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException ");
      }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println("SQLException ");
      }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Exception ");
      }finally {
            if (con== null) {
               System.out.println("Result: null");
            }else{
               return con;
            }
      }
```

Output:

```
      Result: null
```

If URL is wrong , Try...Catch should be cached some exception. But it skipped all exceptions and getConnection("dummy url") returned null.

Although I tried to change to **real url** however the problem is not different.

**Updated:** I modified some code

1. add condition in scope of finally
2. move declaration con varialbe to out of scrope.

It still cannot catch any exception

Comment: Your scope is wrong.

Comment: What URL are you using for DriverManager.getConnection(...). It is obviously throwing some exception. Did you try to debug your code and see which exception is it throwing? But, what I don't understand is, there has to be one of the exception statements from your catch clauses before the line within the finally block `System.out.println("Result: "+ con)`. Also, since you are using this for Android (given that you have put Android Studio as one of the tags), try to see this link [https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/DriverManager] to check what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Its throwing exception. Check the screenshot https://ibb.co/WnpJXys

And of course as all said your scope is wrong

Comment: Mark.Thanks for your screenshot. But I never get this exception when I run a debug in Android Studio.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using JDBC from an Android app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `con` variable declared in the `try` block is out of scope in the `catch` and `finally` clauses.

The only way that this code could compile is if you have declared another `con` variable ... probably as a field of the enclosing class.

This explains why you are seeing `con` with a `null` value when that apparently cannot happen.  You are printing the *other* `con` variable.

---

Note that `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` won't ever return `null`.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-) states that it returns a `Connection` object, and nothing else.  If the method could return `null`, the documentation would say so explicitly.

---

**UPDATE** Once you have corrected the scoping problem with `con`.  It is now possible that the problem is that you are not catching the exception.  Specifically, it could be an `Error` exception, which might arise if there was a problem loading (say) the appropriate JDBC driver class.

Change

```
  }catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException ");
  }catch(SQLException se){
        System.out.println("SQLException ");
  }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Exception ");
```

to

```
  } catch(Throwable e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

(If you catch an exception for diagnostic purposes, you should always print or log the stacktrace!)

Comment: Yes!! Trowable can catch it. Thank you very much.

Comment: printStackTrace tell this error message : No virtual method group(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; in class Ljava/util/regex/Matcher; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.regex.Matcher' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

Comment: Put the **complete** stacktrace into your question.

Comment: No.  I mean that you should do what I suggested. 1) Add a `printStackTrace()`call to the exception handler.  See my answer.  2) Copy and paste the **text** output by `printStackTrace` into your question.  (Not a comment, not a link to a screenshot, copy and paste the text into the question.)